# how to call .Where() method in linq more than once to act like OR (||)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to create a class that allow me to configure LINQ query at run time by using .Where() method, after completing my class and while testing result was not as I expected so I had an issue and to resolve that I needed to call multiple .Where() method times and it should act like OR || not like AND &&
**Example:**

```
class Program
{

    private static string WhereTest()
    {
        string result = "";

        // List
        string[] lst = { "Sa", "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr" };

        // test 1
        var q1 = from l in lst
                 where l.StartsWith("S") && l.EndsWith("u")
                 select l;
        result = "1st query count: " + q1.Count() 
            + "\n----------------- \nItems: \n------- \n";
        foreach (var item in q1.ToList())
        {
            result += item + "\n";
        }
        result += "\n";
        result += "\n";

        // test 2
        var q2 = from l in lst
                 where l.StartsWith("S") || l.EndsWith("u")
                 select l;
        result += "2nd query count: " + q2.Count() 
            + "\n----------------- \nItems: \n------- \n";
        foreach (var item in q2.ToList())
        {
            result += item + "\n";
        }
        result += "\n";
        result += "\n";

        // test 3
        var q3 = from l in lst
                 select l;
        if (true)
            q3 = q3.Where(l => l.StartsWith("S"));
        if (true)
            q3 = q3.Where(l => l.EndsWith("u"));

        result += "3rd query count: " + q3.Count() 
            + "\n----------------- \nItems: \n------- \n";
        foreach (var item in q3.ToList())
        {
            result += item + "\n";
        }
        result += "\n";
        result += "\n";


        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(WhereTest());
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
            1st query count: 1
            -----------------
            Items:
            -------
            Su


            2nd query count: 3
            -----------------
            Items:
            -------
            Sa
            Su
            Tu


            3rd query count: 1
            -----------------
            Items:
            -------
            Su
```

In my example q3 return the same result of q1

So I need to know if I can make q3 return me the same reult of q2.

Regards

Comment: Thanks @James yes its the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LINQ to SQL or other queryable-based providers, [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is the solution. It doesn't let you call `Where` multiple times, but it lets you create a predicate dynamically using multiple calls.

For LINQ to Objects, you can create your own equivalent of `PredicateBuilder` using delegates instead of expression trees, [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094930/linq-to-objects-predicate-builder). Just to make this answer complete in its own right, here's the same code again:

```
public static class DelegatePredicateBuilder
{
  public static Func<T, bool> True<T>()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Func<T, bool> False<T>() { return f => false; }

  public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this Func<T, bool> expr1,
                                     Func<T, bool> expr2)
  {
      return t => expr1(t) || expr2(t);
  }

  public static Func<T, bool> And<T>(this Func<T, bool> expr1,
                                     Func<T, bool> expr2)
  {
      return t => expr1(t) && expr2(t);
  }
}
```

So you'd use something like:

```
var predicate = DelegatePredicateBuilder.False<string>();

if (someCondition)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(l => l.StartsWith("S"));
}

if (someCondition)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(l => l.EndsWith("u"));
}

query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: - Download LinqKit.dll. 
- Add a reference. 
- Use it :)      `IQueryable<Item> q = from i in Items where i.Active == true select i;
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Item>();
if (includeTitle)
 predicate = predicate.Or(i => i.HeaderText == SearchWord);
if (includeSubTitle)
 predicate = predicate.Or(i => i.SubHeaderText == SearchWord);
q = q.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();`

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`System.Linq.Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb506649.aspx)

```
// List
string[] lst = { "Sa", "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr" };

Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr1 = t => t.StartsWith("S");
Expression<Func<string, bool>> expr2 = t => t.EndsWith("u");

var filter = new List<Expression>();

if (true)
{
    filter.Add(expr1);
}

if (true)
{
    filter.Add(expr2);
}

var input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "input");
var result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(bool), "result");

var blockExpression = Expression.Block(
    new[] { result },
    Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Or(Expression.Invoke(expr1, input), Expression.Invoke(expr2, input)))

    );

var x = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(blockExpression, new[] { input });

var func = x.Compile();

var res = lst.Where(func);


foreach (var re in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(re);
}
```

Comment: @Owidat: How is this easier or simpler than using the `PredicateBuilder` approach? Note that it's also more limited, as it requires expression trees, which don't allow for everything that delegates allow.

Comment: @Jon SKeet: You are right PredicateBuilder is great it, solved my problem and the key thing is AsExpandable method if you are using Entity Framework, The AsExpandable method is part of LINQKit http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx, 
and after I used it in my class, (Using LINQ to Entity Visualizer) I noticed that the query is 100% what I was looking for. 
I love using LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework, Entity Visualizer, PredicateBuilder, LINQKit and LINQPad. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this.

```
q3 = q3.Where(l => l.EndsWith("u") || l => l.StartsWith("S"));
```

If you looking for dynamic way of building query following link has predicate builder that help you.

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx